# Help me with name of this type of cable to charge my drone.I want usb to female end connector

Tags: usb, connector, charger, lipo

[image: ma]
I have old remote control helicopter in my toys and I want to charge it via USB.But to purchase it online i am not aware of it's name.Help me with name for connector as shown below. Usb to female end is required.
Cha is mentioned on male end at helicopter.

Comment: Are you sure it's 5v?

Comment: What you need is not the connector, but rather knowledge of the charging scheme.  Most toys of this sort put the charge controller in whatever feeds the cable.  Just connecting a voltage source to the aircraft would be unworkable and dangerous.